# Retrieving specific URLs with HtmlAgilityPack C#

Tags: c#, html, url, html-agility-pack

I'm currently *attempting* to use HtmlAgilityPack to extract specific links from an html page. I tried using plain C# to force my way in but that turned out to be a real pain. The links are all inside of `<div>` tags that all have the same class. Here's what I have:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument html = web.Load(url);

//this should select only the <div> tags with the class acTrigger
foreach (HtmlNode node in html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='acTrigger']"))
{
    //not sure how to dig further in to get the href values from each of the <a> tags
}
```

and the sites code looks along the lines of this

```
            <li>
                <div class="acTrigger">
                    <a href="/16014988/d/" onclick="return queueRefinementAnalytics('Category','Battery')">
                        Battery                                 <em>&nbsp;(1)</em>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="acTrigger">
                    <a href="/15568540/d/" onclick="return queueRefinementAnalytics('Category','Brakes')">
                        Brakes                                 <em>&nbsp;(2)</em>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="acTrigger">
                    <a href="/11436914/d/1979-honda-ct90-cables-lines" onclick="return queueRefinementAnalytics('Category','Cables/Lines')">
                        Cables/Lines                                 <em>&nbsp;(1)</em>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </li>
```

There are a lot of links on this page, but the `href` I need are contained inside of those `<a>` tags which are nested inside of the `<div class="acTrigger">` tags. It would be simple if each `<a>` shared unique classes, but unfortunately only the `<div>` tags have classes. What I need to do is grab each one of those `href`s and store them so I can retrieve them later, go to each page, and retrieve more information from each page. I just need a nudge in the right direction to get over this hump, then I should be able to do the other pages as well. I have no previous experience with this HtmlAgilityPack and all the example I find seem to want to extract all the URLs from a page, not specific ones. I just need a link to an example or documentation, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to change your select to include the `<a>` tag: `//div[@class='acTrigger']/a`. That way your `HtmlNode` is your `<a>` tag instead of the div.

To store the links you can use `GetAttributeValue`.

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in html.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='acTrigger']/a"))
{
    // Get the value of the HREF attribute.
    string hrefValue = node.GetAttributeValue( "href", string.Empty );
    // Then store hrefValue for later.
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer! The /a let me get into the <a> tag and the node.GetAttributeValue pulled the string out for me. Thanks a million! Do you know know of any good sources to learn how the syntax of SelectNodes works? It's a bit whacky

Comment: @KevinD if I recall correctly, it uses Xpath. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp